# Issues with a method and array

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm currently in an intro to java course and I am very much stuck on a problem. I've worked the entire thing out myself, yet the answer is not accepted by the homework system that we use, and is giving me a compilation error. I was hoping someone could shed light on my error.. Here is my Question:

Write a static method named `listCountriesOfOrigin`, to be added to the Bowl class, which is passed an array of Bowl objects, and prints to the console in a column the country of origin of each of Bowl objects in the array.

The Bowl class is given below.

```
public class Bowl {
    private double weight;
    private boolean empty;
    private String origin; // country of manufacture

    public Bowl(double w, boolean e, String origin) {
        weight = w;
        empty = e;
        this.origin = origin;
    }

    public double getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public boolean getEmpty() {
        return empty;
    }

    public String getOrigin() {
        return origin;
    }

    public void setEmpty(boolean emptyStatus) {
        empty = emptyStatus;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return ("from " + origin + " weight: " + weight);
    }
}
```

Here are my solutions:

With a static header/return statement in for loop

```
public static String listCountriesOfOrigin (Bowl[] bowls) {
  for(int i = 0; i < bowls.length; i++) {
    String origin = bowls[i].getOrigin();
    return origin;
  }
}
```

A void method with a SOPln statement:

```
public void String listCountriesOfOrigin (Bowl[] bowls) {
      for(int i = 0; i < bowls.length; i++) {
        String origin = bowls[i].getOrigin();
        System.out.println(origin);
      }
}
```

Both are giving me compilation errors, any help would mean a lot to me, and would be very much appreciated!

thank you!

Comment: Are the compilation errors a state secret, or are you allowed to share it with us?  Normally, when a compiler gives you an error, it gives you useful information like what line the error is on and what the actual error is.  I don't know why you feel it necessary to hide that useful info from us when asking us to help you?

Comment: `public static void listCountriesOfOrigin`?

Comment: doesn't look wrong to me. what exact error do you get?

Comment: @ajb
Feedback:
The system has detected compilation errors. This could be caused by:

    Missing semicolon ; at the end of a statement.
    Unclosed braces {}.
    Unclosed parentheses ().
    Unterminated string literals "".
    Invalid method signature.
    Missing return statement.
    Redeclared variable or data member.
    etc.

Comment: I also contacted my TA, who told me that the return type in my header was wrong, but I don't see the issue

Comment: Looks to me like you're expected to get this working on a Java compiler (or IDE) yourself, before you submit it into the homework system.  A Java compiler would tell you exactly where your error is occurring.  If the course didn't provide one and didn't tell you how to do it, ask for a refund.

Comment: MadProgrammer told you the answer to #2.  You have a method that doesn't return anything, but your declaration said it was going to return a `String`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first method isn't returning a result

```
public static String listCountriesOfOrigin (Bowl[] bowls) {
    for(int i = 0; i < bowls.length; i++) {
        String origin = bowls[i].getOrigin();
        return origin;
    }
    // No return here
}
```

The problem is, the compiler can't guarantee that the `return` statement in the `for-loop` will ever be executed...besides, it doesn't really make sense...

Your second attempt is declared properly...

```
//public void String listCountriesOfOrigin (Bowl[] bowls) {
public static void listCountriesOfOrigin (Bowl[] bowls) {
    for(int i = 0; i < bowls.length; i++) {
        String origin = bowls[i].getOrigin();
        System.out.println(origin);
    }
}
```

Based on the requirements, there isn't any need to return anything from these methods, but that's how I read them

Comment: It was right in front of my face. I completely kept looking over the String declaration in my header in my second answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome to the forest, look out for the trees ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your first statement you can only return one value from a function. Therefore it will run through the loop once and only run once. It should work but a little confused on why it would give a compiler error though.

The second one: you can't return void and a String, you must select one.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to tha return statement in your code. Here is the corrected code.

```
public class Bowl {
private double weight;
private boolean empty;
private String origin=null; // country of manufacture

public Bowl(double w, boolean e, String origin) {
    weight = w;
    empty = e;
    this.origin = origin;
}

public double getWeight() {
    return weight;
}

public boolean getEmpty() {
    return empty;
}

public String getOrigin() {
    return origin;
}

public void setEmpty(boolean emptyStatus) {
    empty = emptyStatus;
}

public String toString() {
    return ("from " + origin + " weight: " + weight);
}

public static String listCountriesOfOrigin(Bowl[] bowls) {
    for (int i = 0; i < bowls.length; i++) {
        String origin = bowls[i].getOrigin();
        return origin;
    }
    return null;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Bowl bowl = new Bowl(1.1, true, "USA");
    System.out.println(bowl.getOrigin());

}
```

}

Comment: Based on the requirements, there is no need to return anything from the `listCountriesOfOrigin` method...

Answer (score 0):

Solution1: return statement is within for loop and can be unreachable.
Solution2: return type should be void as it's not returning anything.

Can you please try this?

```
public static List<String> listCountriesOfOrigin(Bowl[] bowls) {
    List<String> originList = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < bowls.length; i++) {
        String origin = bowls[i].getOrigin();
        originList.add(origin);
    }
    return originList;
}
```

Comment: *"Write a static method named listCountriesOfOrigin, to be added to the Bowl class, which is passed an array of Bowl objects, and prints to the console in a column the country of origin of each of Bowl objects in the array"* - There is no need to return anything from the `listCountriesOfOrigin` and it was just a (bad) attempt on the OP's part to solver their own problem

Comment: This still did not compile with my homework, I received the same compilation error as before :

Feedback:
The system has detected compilation errors. This could be caused by:

    Missing semicolon ; at the end of a statement.
    Unclosed braces {}.
    Unclosed parentheses ().
    Unterminated string literals "".
    Invalid method signature.
    Missing return statement.
    Redeclared variable or data member.
    etc.

Answer (score 0):

Lets step through this problem one part at a time.  First the problem says to make a method that is static and named listCountriesOfOrigin.  It can also be determined that the method should be made public if it is going to be used outside the Bowl class.  Next we learn that the method accepts one parameter, an array of Bowl objects.  Finally we learn what the method has to do, print a column of the Bowl object's origins.  That is all.

Now lets look at what your methods accomplish.

```
public static String listCountriesOfOrigin (Bowl[] bowls) {
    for(int i = 0; i < bowls.length; i++) {
        String origin = bowls[i].getOrigin();
        return origin;        
   }
   //returns nothing here.  If for doesn't execute then no return.
}
```

The first method by looking at the first line is public, static, named correctly, and accepts an array of Bowl objects, however, it returns a String object.  This is wrong for two reasons: one, there is no mention of returning anything in the project description and two, it doesn't make sense in the context of the problem.  Is it returning a concatenated string or just one?  The first or the last?  For both reasons the method should return nothing, or be void.  Next you loop through the array, setting and origin variable equal to the ith bowl object in the array and returning it.  You have the right idea but remember the method is not supposed to return anything but print it out instead.  This code block would just return the origin of the first Bowl.

```
//returns String but void
public void String listCountriesOfOrigin (Bowl[] bowls) {
    for(int i = 0; i < bowls.length; i++) {
        String origin = bowls[i].getOrigin();
        System.out.println(origin);
    }
    //No return
}
```

The second method method is public, void, named correctly and accepts an array of Bowl objects as a parameter but like the first example, it tries to return a String.  This is wrong for the reasons above with the added reason that a method can not both return a string and be void.  The code in the method cycles through each Bowl object and prints its origin on a newline, what the Problem asks for.  The only thing wrong with this one is that it should not have String listed as a return type.  Fix that and you should be good.